# When do dividends occur but capital gains not?

Tags: dividends, capital-gain

Consider a one year period.

In what case would a dividend be distributed by a company, but its share price not rise (other than a sudden fluctuation towards the nearing of the calculation period)?

**EDIT: I changed capital gains to share price since I wasn't thinking of the scenario from the point of view of a shareholder, but from that of the company**

Comment: do you mean capital gains from the capital part of the company balance sheet or from the investors' point of view due to hte share price rising?

Comment: You can edit the title along with the body text.

Answer (score 2):

You receive a dividend if you hold the shares on the ex-dividend date.

You receive capital gains when you sell the shares at a higher price than what you bought them for.

So if you don't sell the shares you will receive the dividends but not any capital gains.

Comment: Thanks! However, I was confused between terms. What I meant was, is it possible for (or, rather, has it been seen that) a company's share price has NOT risen, but dividends have been given for a given time period?

Comment: The price could drop 50% and the company (conceivably) could keep paying dividends.

Answer (score -1):

In the US, stock exchanges reduce share price by the amount of the dividend on the ex-dividend date.  That means that you are effectively receiving a cash flow from your own money in your brokerage account.  That dividend is not a profit until share price recovers to the closing price on the day before the ex-dividend date.  To add insult to injury, if this occurs in a non sheltered account, you incur a taxable event as well.

Share price rises and falls based on the auction between buyers and sellers every trading day.  That is a separate issue from the dividend process.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  Stock exchanges don't set prices, buyers and sellers do.  A stock's price might fall on the ex-dividend date, but it's perfectly possible that it might rise if there's demand for the stock.

Comment: You're conflating the process of the stock going ex-dividend with the auction that begins when the stock trades after the market opens.

Comment: @BobBaerker: I've always been told that the drop in stock price is to due to brokers and automatic triggered trades, by professionals whose valuations of the stock drops due to the outflow of capital inherent in the dividend, rather than a feature of the stock exchange. Do you have any source that states that this is an activity by the stock exchange itself; for example, does the London or Tokyo stock exchange not have these regular, near automatic, post-dividend drops?

Comment: @sharur - How do the valuation changes by these  brokers and professionals cause the stock's price to change?  Do they all get together and say, let's drop share price by the some or all of the dividend?  Do they determine the outflow of capital and change everyone's orders on the order book?  Are day orders and GTC orders altered? What are  automatic triggered trades and how do they make the stock's price drop?  What's the process?  Can you provide some examples of this?

Comment: continued... As I stated in my Answer, "In the US, stock exchanges reduce share price by the amount of the dividend on the ex-dividend date".   I have no idea how the London or Tokyo stock exchanges handle this.  As for my source that this is an activity by the stock exchange itself, all I have is the price of the stock as evidence.  I'd say that's pretty conclusive.

Comment: @BobBaerker: I think I misunderstood you; when you initially said "stock exchange", I thought you were referring to the people who run the exchange, e.g. NYSE Euronext., but now, I think you may be have been referring to the market/all of the investors. Can you clarify? As for your questions: a dividend, by definition is money (capital) leaving the company (into shareholders pockets). Day orders and GTC orders do not need to be altered, as dividends and their values are announced weeks if not months in advance.

Comment: @BobBaerker: As for your question of collusion, I don't think that the brokers "get together and decide" anything. I think that they all have their own valuations of the stock, based in part by the company's capital reserves. When those reserves drop due to the dividend, the valuation of the company also drops accordingly.  Some thing else that I have always been told is that most stocks are not held or traded by individuals, but by funds (mutual, hedge, pension, etc.), whose controllers make their money not off of good long term decisions, but by day-to-day (or less) changes in prices.

Comment: @sharur 37 - OK, the brokers don't collude.  They each "have their own  valuations of the stock, based in part by the company's capital reserves. When those reserves drop due to the dividend, the valuation of the company also drops accordingly." So how does that translate into a lower share price on the ex-dividend date, given that they are operating individually?  What's the process of getting from (A) to (B)? And how does institutional ownership affect this process?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79711/discussion-between-sharur-and-bob-baerker).